# Replace value in data frame with corresponding value from another column in same dataframe

Tags: r, database, dataframe, replace, data-science

This my data frame **df**

```
country    cum_cases      v_dt_date

MX             3              16
MX             2              18
MX             6              32
```

If the value in the column `v_dt_date == 16` I want to change the value of the row in `cum_cases` to 10.

I tried with this:  `df$cum_cases[df$v_dt_date == 16]<-10`
But is not working.

Desired output

```
country    cum_cases      v_dt_date

MX             10             16
MX             2              18
MX             6              32
```

Comment: Your method should work. What does `class(df$v_dt_date)` return?

Comment: ```class(df$v_dt_date) "numeric"  ```

Comment: The answer you accept is equivalent to your method. But you said your method doesn't work...What's wrong?

Comment: Sorry I correct my mistake the thing is that I need to put the number of the column v_dt_date between "" i.e ```df$cum_cases[df$v_dt_date == "16"] <- 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple options:

```
# Direct assignment - nice and efficient
df$cum_cases[df$v_dt_date == 16] <- 10

# ifelse - generalizes well to more complex cases, 
# e.g., nested conditions, more complex results
df$cum_cases <- with(df, ifelse(v_tdt_date == 16, 10, cum_cases))
```